# Solr Prepared statement with workload segregation by data center

Tags: python, solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

DataStax recommend that [search and transactional workloads are organised into separate virtual data centers](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/production/initializeDCPerType.html).

We have done this, and set up two execution profiles in order to determine which data center our queries are executed against. Our default execution profile `EXEC_PROFILE_DEFAULT` executes against the transactional data center, and our 'search' profile executes against the search data center.

This works fine until we try to create a prepared statement for a solr query, which fails because it tries to prepare it against the transactional data center (well, all nodes really) - there is no parameter to the `Session.prepare()` function to specify an execution profile and I can find no way to prepare a prepared statement against a particular execution profile.

I also tried making the default profile the search profile. This got me a little further - the solr search statement could be prepared, but the driver also tried to prepare it against the transactional data center nodes, raising non-fatal error on those nodes.

Using a `SimpleStatement` works fine - because it is not prepared we can just specify the search execution profile when executing it and everything works.

Just to be clear, the statement is like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM table WHERE solr_query=...
```

and the error from the non-Solr nodes (which don't know that `solr_query` is special) is:

> "Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING"

But I honestly cannot believe that the 'best practice' for solr search is to reject prepared statements and have the nodes recompile the statement on each execution. Elsewhere the docs are very clear in recommending a `PreparedStatement` for any statement you will execute more than once.

What am I missing? How can I use prepared statements for solr search when organising different worloads into different data centers? Or should I not?

Comment: btw, it's not so strict requirement for separating Search & Transactional... It's more for analytics and transactional... Although it may depend on SLAs